# Is it possible to set a option, and then redirect to another page directly from a admin notice link?

Tags: wp-admin, notices, plugin-options

I like to execute a update_options() and stuff and then redirect to another plugins page? Directly after the user clicks a link in a Admin notice.

How would i do that? Ajax? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `/wp-admin/admin-post.php`.

Link:

```
$url = admin_url( 'admin-post.php?action=somethingunique' );
print "<a href='$url'>Update and redirect</a>";
```

Then you should register a callback for that action:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_somethingunique', 'wpse_85825_callback' );
```

And in that callback you can do what you want:

```
function wpse_85825_callback()
{
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        update_option( 'my_option', 'some_value' );

    wp_redirect( admin_url( 'users.php' ) );
    exit;
}
```

Note this is just some untested code, take it as a direction, not as final solution. :)

Comment: Appart from the missing bracket it't working perfectly, i not thaught that this was that easy, seems WP has functions for everything.