# Can I use a form in a dashboard widget?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, dashboard

I'm building a plugin and would like to add a dashboard widget with a custom form. In this form, users should be able to edit a list of strings (add, edit and remove items). Is there a WordPress API to do something like that? I already know how to add a dashboard widget, but I don't know how to make a form in a dashboard widget / how to process the data.

The only thing I can think of is to redirect the user to my options page - there must be a neater way. Is there any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options to use forms in a dashboard widget:

1. Use the parameter `control_callback`. See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API)

   ```
   wp_add_dashboard_widget(
       'my_id',            // $widget_id 
       'my_name',          // $widget_name 
       'my_render_widget', // $callback 
       'my_control'        // $control_callback
   );
   function my_control()
   {
       // print some form elements, WordPress will handle the <form> tag.
   }
   ```
2. If you want to use a form in the main display handler, set the form action to `admin-post.php` and add a callback function for a custom `action` there. [Example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102452/73). When you are done processing the form [redirect back](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85828/73) to the dashboard.

Comment: Great! It works, thanks! I'll accept your answer after a while unless there's a better answer.

Comment: (With 'it' I mean the second approach)